# Replace chars but exclude the word which is using it regex

Tags: regex

I'm working on a problem where for example there is a sentence: "Today **_asf was a null_word day__and __bla__bla**".
What I would like to get is a sentence where all: _ are replaced with space except in the null_word. So the output sentence should look like this: "Today    asf was a null_word day  and   bla  bla  ".

To achieve that I wrote a redux expression:

```
 (\w*((?!null_word)\b\S+)[_]+\w*)
```

This expression selects all the words that are using _ char and excludes null_word. But now, how do I select all the _ chars from these groups?

I've tried separating them with the following:

```
 (\w*((?!null_word)\b\S+)[_]+\w*)[_]
```

but the exampled result is: day__

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind to assert what is directly on the left is not null

```
(?<!\bnull)_+
```

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not

  - `\bnull` Match a wordboundary followed by `null`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `_+` Match 1+ times an undersocre

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmcHsM/1)

In the replacement use a space.

If you want to keep exactly `null_word` you might also match that in a capturing group to keep it, and match an underscore to remove it.

Then in the replacement use capturing group 1.

```
(\bnull_word\b)|_+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KMxBiP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Vmamvg)

Comment: Uuu, thank you I did not even think of solving the problem like this. Thank you!

Comment: The second solution is what I was looking for! But it does not work in python....

Comment: @poppytop In python the capturing group is `\1` See this example https://ideone.com/Vmamvg